# How do I restore the connection with the host after disconnecting from the router?

Tags: c++, wifi, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, platformio

I'm using a Wroom-02 in station mode to exchange some information with my server (I'm using the SecureClient library). I'm trying the case where the router is on but there is no connection with Internet. When I re-establish the router internet connection, the module no longer connects to the host giving as error message "Unknown error code".
How can I solve it without making a reset?

This is the complete code that I'm using.

```
`server_connectionFeedback_t server_sendData(char *pollingBuffer)
{
  server_connectionFeedback_t ret=SERVER_CONNECTION_IN_PROGRESS;

switch(serverManager.phase)
{
    case 0:
        stationClient.setInsecure(); 
        if(!stationClient.connect(SERVER_HOST,SERVER_PORT)) 
        {
            char buffTemp[100];
            stationClient.getLastSSLError(buffTemp,100);
            serialDebug.println(buffTemp);
            ret=SERVER_UNREACHEABLE; 
        }
        else 
        {
            stationClient.print(pollingBuffer); 
            serverManager.phase++;
            serverManager.timeoutReplyServer=SERVER_TIMEOUT_REPLY_SERVER; 
            serialDebug.println(pollingBuffer);
            serverManager.lenghtServerData=0;
        }
    break;

    case 1:
        if(serverManager.timeoutReplyServer) 
        {
            serverManager.lenghtServerData=stationClient.available(); 
            if(serverManager.lenghtServerData!=0) 
            {
                for(uint16_t i=0; i<serverManager.lenghtServerData; i++) 
                {
                    if(!i)
                    {
                        serverManager.buffer=(char*)malloc(2);
                        sprintf(serverManager.buffer,"%c",(char)stationClient.read());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        serverManager.buffer=(char*)realloc(serverManager.buffer,strlen(serverManager.buffer)+2);
                        sprintf(serverManager.buffer,"%s%c",serverManager.buffer,(char)stationClient.read());
                    }
                }
                serialDebug.println(serverManager.buffer);
                String HTTPmessage(serverManager.buffer); 
                if(HTTPmessage.startsWith("HTTP/1.1 200 OK")) 
                {
                    server_contentData=HTTPmessage.substring(HTTPmessage.indexOf("Content-Length: ")+22); 
                    free(serverManager.buffer); 
                    serverManager.phase=0; 
                    ret=SERVER_REPLY_OK;
                }
                else
                {
                    free(serverManager.buffer);
                    serverManager.phase=0;
                    ret=SERVER_BAD_REPLY;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            ret=SERVER_NO_REPLY;
    break;
}
return ret;
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this bit of code and modify to fit.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#ifndef STASSID
#define STASSID "your-ssid"
#define STAPSK  "your-password"
#endif

const char* ssid     = STASSID;
const char* password = STAPSK;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
```

All of the code posted above needs to be included in your setup function. Then if you want to reconnect in the middle of your loop function, just insert the following from the above code.

```
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
```

Also, just so you know, all of this code can be found in the examples of the Arduino IDE for the ESP8266WiFi Client.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't say in the question, that the module, besides communicating as a client to my server, also works as a server to communicate with my app always through the router (the app is connected via wifi to the same router) and communications occur regularly. So I don't understand why, once the internet connection is restored, communications with the server are no longer taken up.

Comment: You may have to call the server function after the 
`while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }`
to remedy that issue. If you were to post your complete code, it may help to diagnose the issue.